# How to Count number of people on a rolling period with SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, date-range

I'm trying to count the number of people who bought a product on a 1 year moving period using SQL.

for example :
In August 2022, the number of people from September 2021 to August 2022

In September 2022, the number of people from October 2021 to September 2022
In October 2022, the number of people from November 2021 to October 2022
....

Here is the code I'm using for now,
I'm doing a for loop to create a query on the 1st 12 months and incrementing by 1 to get the result on each single month. I'd like to know how I can do that by only using SQL and what is the best way to do this.

```
for i in range(1, 13):
        query = f"""
              SELECT
                FORMAT_DATE("%B %Y", DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL {i} MONTH)),
                APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(NB_buyer) AS NB_buyer
              FROM
                Table
              WHERE
      
                AND DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) BETWEEN DATETIME_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL {i+12} MONTH)
                AND DATETIME_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL {i-1} MONTH)
                {conditions}
                UNION ALL
```

I hope my question is clear
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please state which program language you are using. Python, dbt? Well, this can be solved by a window function in BigQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74280106/how-do-i-calculate-a-rolling-average-over-a-specific-range-timeframe-in-bigquery/74280715#74280715   `Select * , count(distinct NB_buyer) over WIN1_range from yourtable  window WIN1_range as (order by unix_date(date(timestamps)) range between 12 PRECEDING and current row)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm using python. 
I'm launching my query in big query from pycharm